# Manage GSM Modem response

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, gsm

---

I'm creating a small program in Visual Basic, using Visual Studio 2010, which communicates with a GSM modem via serial port.
The connection works, I can even communicate properly with the modem and I can also send sms and mms .. But I can not handle the modem answers ... I'll explain:
If I send a command like AT + CSQ modem replies with + CSQ 22.0. This command gives me the value of the signal as a response on a scale of 0-30 ... I can see on the screen (in a dedicated console) but I would like to manage the response in the sense that I would do something like that

```
IF (answer.text = "+CSQ 22,0") Then 
      label1.text = "Good"
ELSE
       label1.text = "Bad"
END IF
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to parse the response.  That ought to be as easy as String.SubString() to carve out the digits, Double.TryParse() to convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SerialPort ReadLine method to get the response to the command you send.